# Convert DOM element encoding from CP1251 to UTF-8

Tags: java, xml

I have a simple server-side code that takes request xml and inserts it as string into Oracle database Clob column. The problem is that client-side sends request xml with CP1251 encoded text, but I need to insert it into Oracle with UTF-8 encoding.
Now the code that I use for CP1251 is:

```
        Element soapinElement = (Element) streams.getSoapin().getValue().getAny();  //retrieve request xml      
        Node node = (Node) soapinElement;
        Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();         
        LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput output = domImplLS.createLSOutput();
        output.setEncoding("CP1251");
        Writer stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        output.setCharacterStream(stringWriter);
        serializer.write(document, output);
        String soapinString = stringWriter.toString();
```

This code recognizes text encoded in CP1251.
The task is to make the same but with readable text encoded in UTF-8. Please suggest any ideas.

I tried this, but it produced unreadable characters instead of cyrillic:

```
        Element soapinElement = (Element)   streams.getSoapin().getValue().getAny();            
        Node node = (Node) soapinElement;
        Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();         
        LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput output = domImplLS.createLSOutput();
        output.setEncoding("CP1251");
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        output.setByteStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        serializer.write(document, output);
        byte[] result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "CP1251");
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[10];
        int read;
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }           
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
        String soapinString = out.toString();
```

Comment: I don't understand you question. A String doesn't have any encoding. Encoding is only used when transforming a String to bytes (and vice-versa). So, if your database column is a varchar and is configured to use UTF8, then storing the string into the column will encode it in UTF8, whatever the encoding of the original XML file is.

Comment: @JBNizet `output.setEncoding("CP1251");` produces a header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1251"?>` and i don't like it. it should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Why do you set the encoding to CP1251 if you want it to be UTF-8?

Comment: @JBNizet because if I do `output.setEncoding("UTF-8");` then I will get `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Applicant_Place_Born>ÐÐÐ . ÐÐÐ¡ÐÐÐ</Applicant_Place_Born>` inserted into Oracle, which contains unreadable characters, a cyrillic character set originally. That is because client-side encodes it as CP1251.

Comment: No. That is probably because your Oracle database isn't configured to store strings as UTF-8. As I said, a String doesn't have any encoding. And you're serializing your XML to a String.

Comment: @JBNizet we used another server-side implementation before. it inserted an xml text with header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and correct cyrillic text into Oracle. How then could that be? Unfortunately, we can not see the source code of that implementation.

Comment: @JBNizet I wrote my own client and set encoding to UTF-8 for sending soap message. It worked fine, everything was correct. So as with CP1251. But it is not correct when I receive xml from client-side described above. So I believe Oracle is configured to store UTF-8 and problem is when streams object is cast to Element. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can decode the CP1251 characterset Data like below

```
Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Charset cp1251charset = Charset.forName("CP1251");

// decode CP1251
        CharBuffer data = cp1251charset.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(result));
```

and encode to UTF-8 character set

```
// encode UTF-8
        ByteBuffer outputBuffer = utf8charset.encode(data);
```

and convert the ByteBuffer to byte[]

```
// UTF-8 Value        
        byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();
```

This should probably solve your issue.